# Search for ObjectId of a document: pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I want to access a document in collection by 'name' attribute for getting its ObjectId so that i can insert that unique objectid to other document for reference.

```
cursorObject = db.collectionIngredient.find({'name': 'sugar'})
```

I want `_id` field of cursorObject.

```
cursorObject.'_id' or cursorObject._id not working.
```

I have tried `__getitem__`, `__getattribute__` and so much internet surfing but couldn't able to find a way.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as @jjmartinez pointed out, `find` returns a cursor, which you need to iterate over, in order to get hold of the *documents* returned by your query. The `_id` field belongs to the documents, not the cursor.

I'm guessing that in your case the name is unique, so you can avoid cursor/iterating if you use `find_one` instead of `find`. Then you get the document directly.

Then, to access the `_id`, you just need a standard dict-item access:

```
id = doc['_id']
```

So we get:

```
ingredient = db.collectionIngredient.find_one({'name': 'sugar'})
if ingredient is not None:
    id = ingredient['_id']
else:
    id = None
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do `cursorObject = db.collectionIngredient.find({'name': 'sugar'})` you have a collection of documents, not a single element. So you need to explore all the collection. You need to iterate inside the cursor:

```
  try:
    cursorObject = db.collectionIngredient.find({'name': 'sugar'})

except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]


for doc in cursorObject:
    print doc
```

Here you have the [Pymongo Tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html)